# C# List of Strings: Prevent Printing the Same Index Twice

Tags: c#, list, mono

Okay, this is the shortened down code, adapted from the program that I mentioned before completely wiping the contents of this post. Scroll to the bottom, there's default output commented out for you as well:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace StackExchange {
    class MainClass {
        List<String> inputs = new List<String> ();
        public String line;

        public static String file = "This is a file";

        public static String choice1 = "Determine where the tracks go";

        public static String[] hw = {
            "Value 1",
            "Value 3"
        };

        public static String[] rgb = {
            "Value 1",
            "Value 2", 
            "Value 3"
        }; 

        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            MainClass main = new MainClass();

            main.inputs.Add(file);
            main.inputs.AddRange (hw);
            main.inputs.Add(choice1);
            main.inputs.AddRange (rgb);

            foreach (string value in main.inputs) { 
                //Console.Write (Text.inputs.IndexOf(value));
                main.line = "|     " + main.inputs.IndexOf(value) + "     |     " + value;
                Console.WriteLine (main.line);
            }
        }
    }
}

        // The output when the program gets run:

        //|     0     |     This is a file
        //|     1     |     Value 1
        //|     2     |     Value 3
        //|     3     |     Determine where the tracks go
        //|     1     |     Value 1
        //|     5     |     Value 2
        //|     2     |     Value 3
```

NOW, paste it and compile it into whatever IDE or notepad you prefer to use to compile C# programs, it runs just as described.

Instead of:

```
        //|     0     |     This is a file
        //|     1     |     Value 1
        //|     2     |     Value 3
        //|     3     |     Determine where the tracks go
        //|     1     |     Value 1
        //|     5     |     Value 2
        //|     2     |     Value 3
```

How do I make the left side go up 0-7 like this:

```
        //|     0     |     This is a file
        //|     1     |     Value 1
        //|     2     |     Value 3
        //|     3     |     Determine where the tracks go
        //|     4     |     Value 1
        //|     5     |     Value 2
        //|     6     |     Value 3
```

Thank you for any help possible at this given time.

---

**EDIT 1**

So, I got this far based on @MetaColon's response below. What I'm trying to do is get the program to display both index and element side-by-side as in my first example. In this example, I get @MetaColon's response working side-by-side with part of the original.

Can anyone marry the two segments below?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace StackExchange {
    class MainClass {
        List<String> inputs = new List<String> ();
        public String line;

        public static String file = "This is a file";

        public static String choice1 = "Determine where the tracks go";

        public static String[] hw = {
            "Value 1",
            "Value 3"
        };

        public static String[] rgb = {
            "Value 1",
            "Value 2", 
            "Value 3"
        }; 

        static string value;


        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            MainClass main = new MainClass();

            main.inputs.Add(file);
            main.inputs.AddRange (hw);
            main.inputs.Add(choice1);
            main.inputs.AddRange (rgb);

                for (int i = 0; i < main.inputs.Count; i++)
                {
                    main.line = $"|     {i}     |     {value}";
                    Console.WriteLine(main.line);
                }

                foreach (String value in main.inputs) { 
                    main.line = "     |     " + value;
                    Console.WriteLine (main.line);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // The output when the program gets run:

    //|     0     |     
    //|     1     |     
    //|     2     |     
    //|     3     |     
    //|     4     |     
    //|     5     |     
    //|     6     |     
    //     |     This is a file
    //     |     Value 1
    //     |     Value 3
    //     |     Determine where the tracks go
    //     |     Value 1
    //     |     Value 2
    //     |     Value 3
```

---

**EDIT 2** Fixed boneheaded mistakes because I don't know how to read apparently.

Comment: _"so that you don't necessarily have to go through a GitHub repo"_ -- the way you accomplish that is to create a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, and include that in your post. Making the Stack Overflow community choose between trying to peer through a knot-hole in the fence or having to browse your entire project is no choice at all. Most people will just move on to the next question. See also [ask], and make sure you read the articles linked at the bottom of that page.

Comment: It also is not clear _what_ the problem is. So when you fix your question, make sure you remove all of the irrelevant text (about e.g. your Python program, terminal application, etc.) and provide detailed information about what the [mcve] does now, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble figuring out.

Comment: Wow, didn't know the mods were going to crucify me. Okay, I'll have ~2k LoC up tomorrow. I posted the pictures because describing the problem is... difficult. Thanks for the feedback, Peter.

Comment: Okay, I know what I need to do. It's been so long since I've posted anything on the Stack Exchange network that I actually forgot to reinvent the wheel. (I'm not at a PC, and this is C# we're talking about)

Comment: Post a bit of code and describe the problem you are having.

Comment: Got it, and the code, omw :)

Comment: Is the solution I'm after clear now? I wiped the entire thing, and this rewrite is fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem is that you have multiple items with the same name (e.g. *Value 1, Value3*). So the `IndexOf` method returns the first index of the element found. So for *Value 1* there are two indices, one with the index 1 and one with the index 4. While `IndexOf` returns the lowest index you want the higher index in that case. What you can do is to use a `for` loop or add an index. I'd use a for loop for that case:

```
//...
for (var i = 0; i < main.inputs.Count; i++)
{
    value = main.inputs[i];
    main.line = $"|     {i}     |     {value}";
    Console.WriteLine(main.line);
}
//...
```

Comment: So how do I get "value" to work? In the foreach loop, "value" was assigned at the same time "i" would be in this for loop.

Comment: If you can make this work, I'll gladly mark this as the answer and call it a day.

Comment: @MGageMorgan I'm sorry, I forgot to assign the value field.

Comment: You are a genius, sir. :P